# Black screen when pressing Windows + L

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I've recently installed the Ubuntu-based "Elementary OS" alongside Windows 8, and I have a problem with the shortcut <kbd>[image] (Windows)</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

In the CLI I'm using at work, this is a shortcut to clear the screen, so I keep triggering it by accident, and whenever I do on Elementary I get a black screen with only the cursor.

If music is playing, it cuts off, as if I was being logged out. I can press a bunch of keys, nothing changes, I always get the black screen and I have to reboot.

What is <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> supposed to trigger, and how can I fix this black screen?

Comment: Typically, *clearing* the screen is `Ctrl-l`...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that's good to know, but I keep pressing Windows + L by accident. I guess I'll get used to it soon, but still I would like to know what is causing this problem so that I can fix it.

Comment: Look in your keyboard settings: `Win-l` is probably configured to lock the console.

Comment: I looked in the keyboard shortcuts and Windows + L is not assigned to anything there .. weird

Comment: Is there a flashing cursor (underline or block) in the upper left hand corner? Or is the screen totally black with no features whatsoever? I'm wondering if Alt+F7 or Alt+F8 gets you back to your GUI

Comment: Elementary is based on Ubuntu, and that's what I'm running, and there it means: "Lock screen".  Just bind the key combination to something else and it'll go away...  If this is good enough as an answer, let me know and I'll convert it to a (more detailed) answer...

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem, I now am using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to lock the screen, as <kbd>[image] Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is not configured to lock the console in keyboard settings.